# Centering two images side-by-side with captions

Tags: html, css, image, row, center

I'm making a webpage, and I want a row of two images in each with captions underneath them. I already got the images set up like this, I just need the captions:

```
<div class = "container">
    <img class = "pic" src = "palibutt.jpg">
    <img class = "pic" src = "aaah_lionpali.jpg">
    <img class = "pic" src = "fantapali.jpg">
    <img class = "pic" src = "paliworshipsun.jpg">
    <img class = "pic" src = "dawpali.jpg">
    <img class = "pic" src = "omgpali.jpg">
    <img class = "pic" src = "paliberries.jpg">
    <img class = "pic" src = "olderpaliberries.jpg">
    <img class = "pic" src = "ipadpali.jpg">
    <img class = "pic" src = "palinormal.jpg">
</div>

.pic {
    border-radius:100px;
    padding:10px;
    width:550px;
}

.container{
    text-align:center;
}
```

I already tried the figure and figcaption tags, they made only one image be in the center.

Comment: Try giving the container a width that is equal to two images side by side (plus margins and padding), then set the margin of the container to auto. `.container{width:1140px; margin:auto;}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTML5 `figure` element to wrap each image and then add a `figcaption` element within each to conation your captions.

You can set the `display` property of the figures to `inline-block` to get them to appear adjacent to each other and then style them similarly to how you're currently styling the images with your `.pic` class.

Comment: I tried that, but I want to have two images in a row, and when I do that it only allows me to have one image in a row. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Either change the `display` property of the `figure` elements to `inline-block`, use floats or give flexbox a try.

Comment: Oh, changing the display property of the figure elements worked, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer to include that information. If I've answered your question to your satisfaction, could you accept my answer, please? :)